# Why am I getting "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I can't get my head around this error. I'm coming in another developers project and he has used the code provided to retrieve several reports and all functions as it should , however I keep getting the error in the title when I created a similar report.

Where and what needs to be in place to make this mapping work correctly.
Please advise if more code is needed.
**Also note it's an ASP.NET MVC 3 application**

The controller....

```
    case ReportType.BS_Report:
            {
                model.BSReport = "Company name";

                var records = _docsRepo.PaginatedBS_Reports(model.BSReport,
                                                                            model.From,
                                                                            model.To,
                                                                            currentPageIndex,
                                                                            pageSize,
                                                                            out totalRecords);

                var TimeRec = Mapper.Map<IList<BS_Report>, IList<BSModel>>(records);

                var TimeRecdModel = TimeRec.ToReportPagedList(currentPageIndex,
                                                                            pageSize,
                                                                            model,
                                                                            totalRecords);

                return PartialView("BS_Report", TimeRecdModel);
            }
```

Everything works as it should until it reaches this line...

```
   var TimeRec = Mapper.Map<IList<BS_Report>, IList<BSModel>>(records);
```

BS_Report class...

```
     public class BS_Report : ReportBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

BSModel....

```
      public class BSModel : ReportBaseModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
 }
```

Other report case uses exact same code...

```
     case ReportType.Full_Report:
            {
                var records = _docsRepo.PaginatedFullReportReports(model.ReportedOn,
                                                                            model.From,
                                                                            model.To,
                                                                            currentPageIndex,
                                                                            pageSize,
                                                                            out totalRecords);

                var TimeRecord = Mapper.Map<IList<FullReport>, IList<FullReportModel>>(records);

                var TimeRecordModel = TimeRecord.ToReportPagedList(currentPageIndex,
                                                                            pageSize,
                                                                            model,
                                                                            totalRecords);

                return PartialView("FullReport", TimeRecordModel);
            }
```

Comment: What do you base classes look like?

Comment: Could you give us the complete error message? Usually it also tells you which particular mapping operations fails.

Comment: ReportBase is empty. ReportBaseMOdel, has one property - public string CustomerName {get;set;}

Comment: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
BS_Report -> BSModel
Tracker.Persistence.Reports.BS_Report -> Tracker.ViewModels.ReportModels.BSModel

Destination path:
IList`1[0]

Source value:
Tracker.Persistence.Reports.BS_Report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to 'Create' a mapping for your new report.  Search the codebase for some calls to 'CreateMap' that operate on whatever report type the previous developer had used.  You will likely need to create one for your `BS_Report` type.

Comment: I'll update the code to show how previous developer has written it (its identical), so I'm not sure where any "createMap", could be. I put on break-points, but all program does on that line of code for the working reports, is hang for a few sec's then moves on.

Comment: CreateMap would most likey be in a section of code that would only be called on application startup.  Start from Application_OnStart in the global.asax.cs file and see if anything looks promising there.  You have to use CreateMap to register a mapping for each and every type you plan to later map in your code.  I think it has to be in there somewhere.

Comment: According to your edit, you should find some reference like Automapper.CreateMap<FullReport, FullReportModel> somewhere in your codebase.  Or maybe AutoMapper.CreateMap<IList<FullReport>,IList<FullReportModel>>.

Comment: Got it, Good man, I was indeed missing, Mapper.CreateMap<BS_Report, BSModel>(); from a Configure method found in ViewModelProfile class.